# Android manifest errors

Tags: android, attributes, android-manifest

I tried to create application name by my language but I got errors from android manifest
Tag  attribute package has invalid character '�'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chơi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Is there anyone can help me with this bug, I tried Google but it didn't show any positive results.

Comment: use normal English characters for application name.

Answer (score 2):

`Don't` use any `special character` in your package name. Use only simple English character in `manifest`.

Answer (score 1):

change the manifest like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.choi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

change the special character from your package name,and give o

After that run..it will compile successfully

Answer (score 0):

in your package name, you have this word: "chơi" with maybe indian alphabetical characters!

You can change "ơ" by "o".

or try to replace it with the unicode character: \u01A1